# Excel 365 - Name box contents is flashing

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've just noticed that in my Excel instance, the content of the 'Name Box' in the top left corner is flashing regardless of which cell I am in, or whether I have selected a named range using its drop-down function.  Can anyone please help, I have never noticed this before and no luck googling what it means...

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to run Excel in safe mode? Enter `excel /safe` in Run dialog for a test. In addition, update your Office to check this issue.

Comment: I ran the office update and this hasn't happened since, thank Emily, I will keep eyes out for it coming back, I hate it when things just act odd, then stop...!  Thanks for the comment anyway! :-)